# Wordpress: Installing Plugin error -> Could not create directory

Tags: permissions, wordpress, ftps

this has been asked again and again, but none of the solutions I found actually works for me. I'm testing a new server (Ubuntu server 14.04) and have gone through the whole installation process of the various required software. So far I can access my internal web page via 
   `http://myInternalIP/wordpress/`
I added there a dummy post and it looks ok.

Now I wanted to add a plug-in, but I'm having major trouble with that.
So here is what I have done.

I added a new user called ftps that has it's home dir in 
    /usr/share/wordpress/
and this is part of

```
~$ groups ftps

ftps : ftps www-data
```

When I try to add a plug-in, all goes well until I get the following message:

`Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-importer.0.6.1.zip…`
   `Unpacking the package…`
   `Could not create directory.`
   `Return to Importers`

So the general answer I found in many posts, is that this is a permission issue. Fine. Well I'm fighting with the permission issues since xx hours. So here is a brief summary of what I've done:

> 1. I've tried changing ownerships and groups around (www-data, my user name, ftps). It did not work.
> 2. I've changed permissions to 777 to all the wordpress directory in /usr/share/wordpress.
> 3. I've tried the following commands:

```
sudo -u helder touch /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/test.txt

sudo -u ftps touch /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/test.txt

sudo -u www-data touch /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/test.txt
```

All of these commands generated a file succesfully in the specific directory.

My feeling is that permissions are not the issue, but I might be wrong... what should I look out for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable `write_enable=YES` in the file `vsftpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vsftpd` as your FTP server and have enabled passive connections, you need to add `pasv_promiscuous=YES` to `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`.